GPG unable to sign commits in docker
I've had the following simple gpg setup for a remote development server which has recently stopped working:
#~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf 
allow-preset-passphrase
batch

I'd load my key and then do the following whenever I needed to sign something:
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
/usr/lib/gnupg2/gpg-preset-passphrase -c $private_keygrip < /run/secrets/gpg_passphrase

It used to work fine, but now I'm getting the following error. I believe this is because I'm ssh'ing into my remote server, but I thought using allow-preset-passhphrase would disable restriced mode?

gpg-connect-agent: connection to agent is in restricted mode
ERR 67109115 Forbidden 
gpg-preset-passphrase: problem setting the gpg-agent options
gpg-preset-passphrase: caching passphrase failed: Forbidden

